# Strange Cuda out of Memory behavior in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

Edit: SOLVED- Problem relied on the number of workers, lowered them, problem solved

I am using a 24GB Titan RTX and I am using it for an image segmentation Unet with Pytorch,

it is always throwing Cuda out of Memory at different batch sizes, plus I have more free memory than it states that I need, and by lowering batch sizes, it INCREASES the memory it tries to allocate which doesn't make any sense.

here is what I tried:

**Image size = 448, batch size = 8**

- "RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory"

**Image size = 448, batch size = 6**

- "RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 3.12 GiB (GPU 0; 24.00 GiB total capacity; 2.06 GiB already allocated; 19.66 GiB free; 2.31 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)"

is says it tried to allocate 3.12GB and I have 19GB free and it throws an error??

**Image size = 224, batch size = 8**

- "RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 28.00 MiB (GPU 0; 24.00 GiB total capacity; 2.78 GiB already allocated; 19.15 GiB free; 2.82 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)"

**Image size = 224, batch size = 6**

- "RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 344.00 MiB (GPU 0; 24.00 GiB total capacity; 2.30 GiB already allocated; 19.38 GiB free; 2.59 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)"

reduced batch size but tried to allocate more ???

**Image size = 224, batch size = 4**

- "RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 482.00 MiB (GPU 0; 24.00 GiB total capacity; 2.21 GiB already allocated; 19.48 GiB free; 2.50 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)"

**Image size = 224, batch size = 2**

- "RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 1.12 GiB (GPU 0; 24.00 GiB total capacity; 1.44 GiB already allocated; 19.88 GiB free; 2.10 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)"

**Image size = 224, batch size = 1**

- "RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 1.91 GiB (GPU 0; 24.00 GiB total capacity; 894.36 MiB already allocated; 20.94 GiB free; 1.03 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)"

Even with stupidly low image sizes and batch sizes...

Comment: You might want to consider adding your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED- Problem relied on the number of workers, lowered them, problem solved

Comment: How do you lower the number of worker?

Comment: I am using Pytorch, to reduce the number of workers simply pass a value to the "num_workers" parameter in the data loader, like so:
```
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=16, num_workers=4, shuffle=False)
```
if you use "num_workers=-1" you use all of them

Comment: Got the same problem of yours but already had the num_workers set to 1 - the minimum. I have 500 square images of 500px each, batch_size=1 and got the error: Tried to allocate 46.00 MiB (GPU 0; 32.00 GiB total capacity; 27.71 GiB already allocated; 118.54 MiB free; 28.38 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)